# How do I make the power button shut the laptop down without asking?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, shutdown, gnome-power-manager

The energy options screen, oddly, doesn't have an option for what to do when the power button is pressed!

Translating the three options:

- "Suspend when inactive for:" (it's set to not suspend)
- "When the lid is closed:" (it's set to suspend)
- "When (battery) power is extremely low:" (it's set to power off)

***Where*** are the power button options? They appear when I run Fedora 14 in the same computer.

[image]

Comment: I want exactly the same thing for suspend and can't find it. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options is not available in the UI anymore, but I found it to be still availble in `gconf`.

To attach an action with the power button, enter in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power action_name
```

Where action_name is one of the following:

- suspend
- shutdown
- hibernate
- interactive (ask what to do)

Comment: Is there a way to make that system-wide (including from the login screen) without having to configure it for each user?

Comment: I don't know, sorry